# Plot points on cartographic projection, detail

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, projection, geo

How can I create a plot like this one, i.e. with "bent" coordinate lines?

http://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1206b.jpg

That is, I would like a map projection (e.g. mollweide), in a certain degree range (30 to 120 degree, -10 to -40 deg).

I just need the coordinate lines and points (i.e. no background image at the moment).

Any area-conserving or angle-conserving projection would be acceptable, mollweide is what I tried first.

I tried to use matplotlib with

```
subplot(111, projection="mollweide")
```

but it gives me an error when I try to set xlim/ylim.

When I try in Basemap (m.scatter), the points are not plotted inside the map.

The reason I want to create this plot is that I have points in degrees, but if I plot them as x/y their angles and areas are distorted (because they are far from 0). I can conserve at least angles or areas if I use a map projection.

Comment: I was able to solve it using http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html . The trick is to do x, y = m(lon, lat) AND m.plot(x, y).